# Does the Random tree algorithm in WEKA uses Information gain?

Tags: weka, entropy

I'm using weka with some db's and i'm trying to understand how works Random tree algorithm. I don't understand if it choose, in every node, a random attribute to split, or if it uses (in every node) the information gain of an attribute to decide which one it has to split. 
Thank you

Regards,
Andrea

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150970/what-splitting-criterion-does-random-tree-in-weka-3-7-11-use-for-numerical-attri/44011124

Comment: thank you so much nekomatic :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What splitting criterion does Random Tree in Weka 3.7.11 use for numerical attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150970/what-splitting-criterion-does-random-tree-in-weka-3-7-11-use-for-numerical-attri)